# Wix darice.cub file missing when building from visual studio 2010

Tags: wix, wix3.5

We have created a simple wix project for a basic windows application. Everything builds fine and the MSI is produced.

However, switching to Release gives the following error message;

```
light.exe(0,0): error LGHT0222: The cube file'C:\Users\julius\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\3V768E95.XWA\CYQG3JK6.XHT\2b4730b4\00186b06_b0b7cb01\darice.cub' cannot be found.  This file is required for MSI validation.
```

If I run our build script which uses msbuild to build the solution everything works fine. So I am thinking it got something to do with the visual studio environment. I have tried making a simple solution with a wix installer and that solution works fine both in debug and release.

Im running this on Windows 7 64 bit box using VS 2010 SP1.

Any ideas what I should look for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Same config here. I just copied it from C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Installer XML v3.6\bin to that location and the error is gone. Weird...

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing as well. The directory keeps changing...frustrating.

Comment: The Fix worked. One slight modification is that with the latest install it puts it in a different location. C:\Program Files (x86)\WiX Toolset v3.7\bin

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix this in VS2013 by simply restarting Visual Studio